# Return True or False if values in a column contain elements from a list of strings R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I want to check if there is a close match between column values and a list of strings. There is rarely a perfect match so %in% is no good.  I'd rather err on the side of caution than miss something, however I'd rather avoid matching potential patterns within each individual word

For example

List:

```
Tenis PLC
Green Company Limited
(DCC) Darth Company Creditors
```

Dataframe

```
ID.  Company Name
10.  Ten LTD
12.  Green Company (GC) LTD
23   MCC
48.  DARTH
```

Return

```
False
True
False
True
```

EDIT: I should mention I have now cleaned the data a little to make it all lowercase and remove any brackets

Comment: Are you looking for match between any word?  Based on the last word 'DARTH', it seems that you may need distance method, but that won't be accurate as well

Comment: Yes, so I want to check if any of the company names are contained within the list or if they are a close match.  I am not sure what the distance method is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### To regenerate your data:

```
l = list(tolower(c('Tenis PLC',
     'Green Company Limited',
     '(DCC) Darth Company Creditors')))

tmp_df = data.frame(Company_Name=c(tolower(c('Ten LTD', 'Green Company (GC) LTD', 'MCC',
        'DARTH'))))
```

#### Solution:

1. Get all the substring divided by space:

```
    split1 = unlist(strsplit(unlist(l), ' '))
```

2. Find whether or not any of the values in `Company_name` contains them (assuming this is what you meant):

```
    sapply(tmp_df$Company_Name,
           function(x) {sum(unlist(strsplit(x, ' ')) %in% split1) >= 1})
```

##### EDIT:

To keep items in `split1` with at least 3 characters:

```
    split1[sapply(split1, nchar) > 3]
```

Comment: That works well.  Now if I could find a way to remove items from unlist1 that are 3 or less characters long that would remove a lot unnecessary elements

Comment: Maybe edit your question, I will add the following answer with an edit.